# Mount SMB/CIFS share within a Docker container

Tags: linux, windows, docker, mount, cifs

I have a web application running in a Docker container. This application needs to access some files on our corporate file server (Windows Server with an Active Directory domain controller). The files I'm trying to access are image files created for our clients and the web application displays them as part of the client's portfolio.

On my development machine I have the appropriate folders mounted via entries in `/etc/fstab` and the host mount points are mounted in the Docker container via the `--volume` argument. This works perfectly.

Now I'm trying to put together a production container which will be run on a different server and which doesn't rely on the CIFS share being mounted on the host. So I tried to add the appropriate entries to the `/etc/fstab` file in the container & mounting them with `mount -a`. I get `mount error(13): Permission denied`.

A little research online led me to [this article about Docker security](http://opensource.com/business/14/9/security-for-docker). If I'm reading this correctly, it appears that Docker explicitly denies the ability to mount filesystems within a container. I tried mounting the shares read-only, but this (unsurprisingly) also failed.

So, I have two questions:

1. Am I correct in understanding that Docker prevents any use of `mount` inside containers?
2. Can anyone think of another way to accomplish this **without** mounting a CIFS share on the host and then mounting the host folder in the Docker container?

Comment: Can you please share the code how you modified /etc/fstab file to have details of network drive? Also, have you done all this in DOCKERFILE?

Comment: @AnkushJain I don't do this very often, but when I do, I usually refer to [this page of documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)

Comment: I wrote a blog here for a complete C#.NET based solution - https://coderjony.com/blogs/mount-a-windows-share-on-linux-container-using-cnet/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes, Docker is preventing you from mounting a remote volume inside the container as a security measure. If you trust your images and the people who run them, then you can use the `--privileged` flag with `docker run` to disable these security measures.

Further, you can combine `--cap-add` and `--cap-drop` to give the container only the capabilities that it actually needs. [(See documentation)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) The `SYS_ADMIN` capability is the one that grants mount privileges.

Answer (score 34):

1. yes
2. There is a closed issue **mount.cifs within a container**

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22197

according to which adding

`--cap-add SYS_ADMIN --cap-add DAC_READ_SEARCH`

to the run options will make mount -t cifs operational.

I tried it out and:

`mount -t cifs //<host>/<path> /<localpath> -o user=<user>,password=<user>`

within the container then works

Comment: I needed to also add `--security-opt apparmor:unconfined`

Comment: This worked for me a while ago, but now it requires `privileged` again :-/

Answer (score 18):

You could use the `smbclient` command (part of the Samba package) to access the SMB/CIFS server from within the Docker container without mounting it, in the same way that you might use `curl` to download or upload a file.

There is a question on [StackExchange Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206415/sending-files-over-samba-with-command-line) that deals with this, but in short:

```
smbclient //server/share -c 'cd /path/to/file; put myfile'
```

For multiple files there is the `-T` option which can create or extract `.tar` archives, however this looks like it would be a two step process (one to create the `.tar` and then another to extract it locally).  I'm not sure whether you could use a pipe to do it in one step.

Answer (score 5):

Do not make your containers less secure by exposing many ports just to mount a share. Or by running it as `--privileged`

Here is how I solved this issue:

- First mount the volume on the server that runs docker.

`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=YourUserName,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) //SERVER/share ~/WinShare`

Change the username, SERVER and WinShare here. This will ask your sudo password, then it will ask password for the remote share.

Let's assume you created `WinShare` folder inside your home folder. After running this command you should be able to see all the shared folders and files in `WinShare` folder. In addition to that since you use the `uid`and `gid` tags you will have write access without using sudo all the time.

- Now you can run your container by using `-v` tag and share a volume between the server and the container.

Let's say you ran it like the following.

`docker run -d --name mycontainer -v /home/WinShare:/home 2d244422164`

You should be able to access the windows share and modify it from your container now.

To test it just do:

`docker exec -it yourRunningContainer /bin/bash`

`cd /Home`

`touch testdocfromcontainer.txt`

You should see `testdocfromcontainer.txt` in the windows share.

Comment: This works, but requires changes on the host, and makes problems in multi-user scenarios in which each container shall have the access rights of a particular user. (OP explicitly asked "[solution which] doesn't rely on the CIFS share being mounted on the host".)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on OSX. There seems to be a special exception being made for mounted filesystems on top of the rootfs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Netshare docker volume plugin which allows to [mount remote CIFS/Samba as volumes.](http://netshare.containx.io/docs/cifs)

Comment: Since the website is no longer available, here is a link to the project's Github page: https://github.com/ContainX/docker-volume-netshare

Note that the last commit was in 2020