# Docker - Mount Windows Network Share Inside Container

Tags: python, linux, windows, docker, boot2docker

I have a small Python application that I'd like to run on Linux in Docker (using boot2docker for now). This application reads some data from my Windows network share, which works fine on Windows using the network path but fails on Linux. After doing some research I figured out how to mount a Windows share on Ubuntu. I'm attempting to implement the dockerfile so that it sets up the share for me but have been unsuccessful so far. Below is my current approach, which encounters operation not permitted at the mount command during the build process.

```
#Sample Python functionality
import os
folders = os.listdir(r"\\myshare\folder name")

#Dockerfile
RUN apt-get install cifs-utils -y
RUN mkdir -p "//myshare/folder name"
RUN mount -t cifs "//myshare/folder name" "//myshare/folder name" -o username=MyUserName,password=MyPassword

#Error at mount during docker build
#"mount: error(1): Operation not permitted"
#Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

**Edit**
Not a duplicate of [Mount SMB/CIFS share within a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989751/mount-smb-cifs-share-within-a-docker-container). The solution for that question references a fix during `docker run`. I can't run `--privileged` if the docker build process fails.

---

**Q: What is the correct way to mount a Windows network share inside a Docker container?**

---

Answer (score 4):

Docker only abstracts away applications, whereas mounting filesystems happens at the kernel level and so can't be restricted to only happen inside the container.  When using `--privileged`, the mount happens on the host and then it's passed through into the container.

Really the only way you can do this is to have the share available on the host (put it in `/etc/fstab` on a Linux machine, or mount it to a drive letter on a Windows machine) and have the host mount it, then make it available to the container as you would with any other volume.

Also bear in mind that `mkdir -p "//myshare/folder name"` is a semi-invalid path - most shells will condense the `//` into `/` so you may not have access to a folder called `/myshare/folder name` since the root directory of a Linux system is not normally where you put files.  You might have better success using `/mnt/myshare-foldername` or similar instead.

An alternative could be to find a way to access the files without needing to mount them.  For example you could use the `smbclient` command to transfer files between the Docker container and the SMB/CIFS share without needing to mount it, and this will work within the Docker container, just as you might use `wget` or `curl` to upload or download files, as is also commonly done in Dockerfiles.

Comment: The question was about Docker. Therefore your answer should be relevant to Docker. It is quite frustrating to be searching for an answer to a question and having to sort through answers that begin with, "Well I haven't used the application you are referring to, and I'm not familiar with it, but here is something that is probably not relevant..."

Comment: @KatherineElizabethLightsey: Sorry, this answer was written three years ago when Docker was very new and experts were not common.  I have since used Docker extensively, so I have updated my answer accordingly.  I hope the improvements are enough to at least earn back the downvote!

Comment: @Mavineous - Done and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you can only use `--privileged` during `docker run`.  You cannot perform `mount` operations without `--privileged`, ergo, you cannot perform mount operations during the `docker build` process.

This is probably by design: the goal is that a Dockerfile is largely self contained; anyone should be able to use your `Dockerfile` and other contents in the same directory to generate the same image; linking things to an external mount would violate this restriction.

However, your question says that you have an application that needs to read some data from a share so it's not clear why you need the share mounted during `docker build`.  It sounds like you would be better off building an image that will launch your application as part of `docker run`, and possibly use [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) to access the share rather than attempting to mount it inside the container.

Comment: I've attempted to run a base Ubuntu image where I've mounted the volume like this: `docker run -v "//myshare/folder name":"//myshare/folder name"`. However, when I enter the container in the interactive mode, the folder is there but none of the files and folders are listed. I suspect this is because the network share is access controlled. My user account above has access to this folder and can navigate the folders when I mount it on a regular Ubuntu VM. Is there anyway for me to use a Docker Volume with an access controlled share?