# Unable to mount cifs filesystem in Docker container

Tags: docker, cifs

I'm on Docker 17.06.0-ce and I'm attempting to mount a CIFS share in a container and only having some luck.  If I use `--privileged`, it works, but that's not desirable for me.  I've tried using `--cap-add` as well as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989751/mount-smb-cifs-share-within-a-docker-container) (even trying with `--cap-add ALL` with no success.

The same mount command works fine on the host system as well.

Here's a simple docker file I've tried playing with

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add --no-cache cifs-utils
```

Run with many different permutations, all with the same result below:

Works:
`docker run --rm -it --privileged cifs-test /bin/sh`

Doesn't Work:
`docker run --rm -it --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --cap-add DAC_READ_SEARCH cifs-test /bin/sh`

Doesn't Work:
`docker run --rm -it --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --cap-add DAC_READ_SEARCH --cap-add NET_ADMIN cifs-test /bin/sh`

Doesn't Work:
`docker run --rm -it --cap-add ALL cifs-test /bin/sh`

And the command:

`mkdir /test && mount.cifs //myserver/testpath /test -o user=auser,password=somepass,domain=mydomain`

And the result from each `run` command above except the first:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Has something changed in Docker that requires `--privileged` all the time for these types of mounts now?  Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Why not mounting it in the host and sharing it with the container in a volume?

Comment: Normally I would if it was a static container, however I'm doing this as part of a CI/CD pipeline and there's over 100 different servers that could potentially be connected to, so it needs to be dynamic.  I think I found a solution using the docker-volume-netshare plugin which supports host-mounting on the fly though.  Need to test it a little more.

Answer (score 1):

I started using `docker-volume-netshare` so far with good success. There are some minor problems, like volumes created with `docker volume create` not being persistent, but nevertheless it looks like this volume driver is quite usable. One advantage is that special caps/privileged mode are not necessary. Here are some hints on how to use it.

**Install (Ubuntu/Debian)**

```
$ curl -L -o /tmp/docker-volume-netshare_0.34_amd64.deb https://github.com/ContainX/docker-volume-netshare/releases/download/v0.34/docker-volume-netshare_0.34_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i /tmp/docker-volume-netshare_0.34_amd64.deb
$ rm /tmp/docker-volume-netshare_0.34_amd64.deb
```

**Configure**

```
$ sudo vi /etc/default/docker-volume-netshare
```

enter as single setting

```
DKV_NETSHARE_OPTS="cifs --netrc=/root/"
```

then

```
$ sudo vi /root/.netrc
```

enter the following settings per host:

```
machine <host>
  username <user>
  password <password>
  domain <domain>
```

Note that `<host>` must be a host name or an IP address followed by a colon (e.g. `10.20.30.4:`)

**Enable the volume driver as a `systemd` service**

Note: if your OS does not support `systemd`, another method to install it as a service is necessary.

```
$ sudo systemctl enable docker-volume-netshare
```

**Use a volume in `docker run` and `docker service create`**

```
$ sudo docker run -it --rm --mount type=volume,volume-driver=cifs,source=<myvol>,destination=<absolute-path-in-container>,volume-opt=share=<ip>:/<share> ubuntu:zesty bash
$ sudo docker service create --name <name> --mount type=volume,volume-driver=cifs,source=<myvol>,destination=<absolute-path-in-container>,volume-opt=share=<host>/<share> <image>
```

Obviously it is not necessary to use the *identical* volume in multiple containers, because the volumes only map to a cifs share which in turn is shared among containers mounting it. As mentioned above, don't use `docker volume create` with this volume driver, as volumes are lost as soon as `docker-volume-netshare` is stopped and/or restarted (and hence on reboot).

**Get help**

```
$ docker-volume-netshare --help
$ docker-volume-netshare cifs --help
```

**Logs**

Hint: for debugging use `DKV_NETSHARE_OPTS="cifs --netrc=/root/ --verbose"` in `/etc/default/docker-volume-netshare` or stop the service and start `docker-volume-netshare cifs --netrc=/root/ --verbose` in a shell)

```
$ dmesg | tail
$ tail -50 /var/log/docker-volume-netshare.log
```

**Resources**

- [github](https://github.com/ContainX/docker-volume-netshare)
- [project](http://netshare.containx.io/)