# external cifs share within docker container (gitlab ci)

Tags: ubuntu, docker, permissions, gitlab, mount

## Hey Stackoverflow community :)

first I've to tell you that im new to docker and ci & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989751/mount-smb-cifs-share-within-a-docker-container) is not working for me.

**Some information regarding enviroment and motivation:**

I'm using a GitLab server in this case for version control a wpad *(auto proxy configuration)* file.

Every change of this file affects about 2000 clients. So i decided to setup ci for that, I'm using [pacparser](https://github.com/pacparser/pacparser) with a small py script to validate the config.
After sucessfull test passing, ci mounts a cifs share, copy original wpad to a wpad.bak and replaces the original with the new tested one.

Everything worked fine, like expected.

A few weeks later a other guy started to migrate some servers and I got into trouble with dependencies and other stuff - this was the reason why I started to move to docker, better begin with docker.

**Back to the issue:**

GitLab CI is starting an Ubuntu Dockercontainer with this config:

```
tls-ca-file = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
image = "ubuntu"
privileged = true
cap_add = ["SYS_ADMIN","DAC_READ_SEARCH"]
disable_cache = false
volumes = ["/cache"]
shm_size = 0
```

the container is cloning pacparser.git and installs some apt reps but if i try to `mount.cifs //remoteserver.domain.local/sharename /mnt/sharename -o usr,pw / credfile` i - *the ci test within docker ubuntu image* - get this output:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

i tried mounting from fstab and/or using interactive bash. i think `privileged = true` can be set to false...

i assume that mounting the share at the docker host and `--mount` the share to the container would work - but i don't like this option.

Thank you for any comment :-)

Comment: The `-o usr,pw / credfile` options are only exemplary, you don't use this command verbatim, right?

Comment: yes that is just exemplary. i wont provide real credentials here. the same mount statement is working from everywhere out of the docker container - with credfile or inline creds

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mount SMB/CIFS share within a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989751/mount-smb-cifs-share-within-a-docker-container)